# Could be possible remove Fabric apiKey from a migration from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I got an android app where Fabric Crashytics is installed. I've followed the official guide of Firebase to migrate from Fabric to Firebase.The migration works correctly and I see all the reports in Fabric and Firebase console.

The problem is that if I want remove the Fabric apikey from manifest.xml because I don't want to see the crash on Fabric, only on Firebase console. If I remove the apikey how I said before the crashes doesn't appear at Firebase console.

I see other questions and at the moment to set up the Crashlytics SDK on Firebase console, I choose that the app was an existing Crashlytics app.

I have other question, when the migration ends Fabric reports will be disappear? and the Fabric apikey would be deprecated also?

Answer (score 0):

No it wont disappear from Fabric if you wont delete it. For Firebase sync you need add google-services.json file from Firebase Console to your project

Comment: I added google-service.json, dependencies and removed the apiKey from Fabric and the crashes doesn't appears at firebase console. Seems how if Firebase crashlytics was connected by old apiKey from Fabric.

Comment: Have you added all Firebase dependencies and doublechecked that app id matches id in google-services.json file? It also might take some time for first crashes appear

Comment: yes, I added google-service.json, dependencies and I checked the id. Also I waited a long time to saw the crash. Seems that if I migrate from fabric to Firebase Crashlytics and removing Fabric apiKey(adding google-service.json and dependencies) doesn't sent reports to Firebase because the Fabric apiKey is necessary to sent reports, if you came from Fabric migration .

Comment: Strange, I did Fabric migration year ago and did not had any issues with removing key. Have you tried clean and rebuild? Or add firebase integration using Android Studio wizard?  Also some fabric plugins still gave to be used for Firebase for example "apply plugin: 'io.fabric'" in gradle. And in activity onCreate "  Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())"

Comment: I found this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497336/firebase-crashlytics-not-working-without-fabric-api-key?rq=1 that say If I select that it's an existing Crashlytics app at the moment of set up Crashlytics SDK, Firebase Crashlytic will expect that the Fabric API key to be present. On the other hand , I don't know how did you do to works without Fabric apikey. Maybe I'm doing incorrectly one step to set up Crashlytics from migration.

Comment: I doublechecked and there is for sure no fabric key, only google-services.json, could it be that you have different flavors with different app id? I was struggling with this situation

Comment: no, I haven't. I am intrigued to know if the migration of your app from Fabric was creating a new project on Firebase and adding inside the app or was linking the app following the migration steps? https://fabric.io/firebase_migration

Comment: we had cloud messaging on firebase and crashlytics on fabric, we did crash logs linking with migration somewhere in options in fabric and also did google-services file update, that was basically it as I remember.

Comment: And anyway if you have google-services.json imported with all necessary Firebase dependancies and correct app id crash logging should work

Answer (score 0):

**If you did the click-through migration you shouldn't remove it**

> Q: Can I remove/change my Fabric API key after migrating to Firebase?
>
> A: If you’ve completed the click-through Fabric migration flow to
>   migrate to Firebase, you can keep using the Fabric Crashlytics SDK. In
>   that case, you should leave your old Fabric API key in your app.
>
> After you link your app, you can choose to upgrade to the Firebase
>   Crashlytics SDK in beta for iOS or Android, which requires making
>   updates to your code.

See also: https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/faq.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

According to this https://get.fabric.io/roadmap Fabric will close on MARCH 31, 2020.